# Trouble adding list when creating dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

Im making a task manager and originally set a dynamic function to create a list with a delete button with the lists task add form, when I created it dynamically to add a column over the lists task add form it stopped working even though I used the same attributes when creating the elements. i am new to this and any help is appreciated

```js
const addColumnBtn = document.getElementById('add-new-column');
const column_inpt = document.getElementById('new-column');

addColumnBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  var ColumnForm = document.createElement("form");
  ColumnForm.setAttribute("method", "post");
  ColumnForm.setAttribute("action", "submit");

  var AddText = document.createElement("input");
  AddText.setAttribute('type', 'add-task');
  AddText.setAttribute('id', 'new-task');
  AddText.setAttribute('name', 'T');
  AddText.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Add Tasks Here');

  var s = document.createElement("button");
  s.setAttribute("type", "button");
  s.setAttribute("value", "add to list");
  s.setAttribute('id', 'Add Task');
  s.textContent = "Add";

  var btn = document.createElement("button");
  btn.textContent = "x";

  ColumnForm.append(AddText);
  ColumnForm.append(s);
  ColumnForm.append(btn);

  var parent = document.getElementById("tasks");
  parent.appendChild(ColumnForm);

  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.parentElement.remove();
  })
})

const addBtn = document.getElementById('add');
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
const inpt = document.getElementById('new-task');

addBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  var btn = document.createElement("button");

  btn.textContent = "x";

  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(inpt.value));
  ul.appendChild(li);
  li.appendChild(btn);

  inpt.value = ""

  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.parentElement.remove();
  })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>To-Do</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="AddTaskColumn">
    <a class="active" href="#">Get-r Done</a>
    <div class="task-box">
      <form role="add-column" id="column">
        <input type="add-column" id="new-column" name="T" placeholder="Add New Column Here" />
        <input type='button' value='add column' id='add-new-column' placeholder="submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="AddTaskToList">
    <a class="active" href="#">Get-r Done</a>
    <div id="task-box">
      <form role="add-task" id="tasks">
        <input type="add-task" id="new-task" name="T" placeholder="Add Tasks Here" />
        <input type='button' value='add to list' id='add' placeholder="Add Task" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="ListOfTasks">
    <b>Stuff To Do</b>
    <ul id="list">
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue you are having is that you need to use event delegation to handle the click events of the dynamically created elements. Basically, you can not attach the listener to the dynamically created element, you need to put it on a static parent element such as the `<ul>` element.

So something like:

```html
<div class="AddTaskColumn">
  <a class="active" href="#">Get-r Done</a>
  <div class="task-box">
    <form role="add-column" id="addColumnForm">
      <input type="text" id="new-column" name="T" placeholder="Add New Column Here" />
      <button type="button" id="add-new-column">Add Column</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="AddTaskToList">
  <a class="active" href="#">Get-r Done</a>
  <div id="task-box">
    <form role="add-task" id="tasks">
      <input type="text" id="new-task" name="T" placeholder="Add Tasks Here" />
      <button type="button" id="add">Add Task</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="ListOfTasks">
  <b>Stuff To Do</b>
  <ul id="list">
  </ul>
</div>
```

```js
// Event delegation to handle delete buttons for tasks
document.getElementById('list').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
    event.target.parentElement.remove();
  }
});

// Add column
document.getElementById('add-new-column').addEventListener('click', function () {
  var newColumn = document.createElement('div');
  newColumn.textContent = document.getElementById('new-column').value;
  newColumn.classList.add('column');
  document.body.appendChild(newColumn);
  document.getElementById('new-column').value = '';
});

// Add task
document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', function () {
  const taskText = document.getElementById('new-task').value;
  if (taskText.trim() === '') return; // Ignore empty tasks
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = taskText;
  const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
  deleteButton.textContent = 'x';
  li.appendChild(deleteButton);
  document.getElementById('list').appendChild(li);
  document.getElementById('new-task').value = '';
});
```